# img height/width ignoring parents div height/width

Tags: html, css

I have had this problem many times and the way i fix it is by adding width and height when declare the img on html such as below:

```
<img src="outside.jpg" width="375px" height="375px">
```

however if I do as below it will not respect the parents div

```
<div class="imgBox">
     <img src="outside.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS parents div

```
.imgBox{
    height: 375px;
    width: 375px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Why does that happen? why does img ignores their parents size?

Comment: set `width:100%` to the img

Comment: FYI, `<img src="outside.jpg" width="375px" height="375px">` - that was wrong to begin with ... the `width` and `height` html attributes take an _integer_ value only, no unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an HTML/CSS problem, the size of a child is not define by the size of his parents. This is due of the default value of height and width.
In CSS default value of height and width is :

```
img{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

`auto` let the browser calculates the height, so it's not the best way.

For a cleaner code use `height: inherit;` and width `width: inherit;` that allows the child inherits this property from its parent element

Answer (score 2):

Image element have always size of displayed image if you do not set different size.

Add this css:

```
.imgBox img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJmyee

Answer (score 0):

```
.imgBox img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

So `img` will never be bigger than its parent.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add class inline with the img url like this:

```
<img src="outside.jpg" class="imgBox">
```